# Owl Carousel Double Dots in Mobile

Tags: html, css, carousel

I'm facing a problem with the dots of owl carousel lib **in mobile**. When you click in one dot to see another item of the carousel, and then pass the slider to see another one, it stays activated. Don't know what to do.

[image: image of the problem]

And here's the link to the live version:
https://victorsaisse.com/carousel/

Thank you

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask]. Links to other sites aren't adequate.

Comment: Also, I see _no_ dots on that site.

Comment: It's in the mobile version, thank you!

Comment: Correction... under 600px they do appear. However, the second dot fades out for me.

Comment: I can't see what's happening in your screenshot - looked at various sizes in Chrome dev tools, and on an actual mobile device too.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.